# Create an Admin Super User in Asp.Net Mvc 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to code for creating the default admin super user from the Startup.cs in Asp.Net Mvc 6, I can add just the all the user roles, but I cannot automatically assign the admin user into the table of AspNetUsers. Can some experts help me to correct the problem as my embedded code below:

```
private async Task CreateRoles(ApplicationDbContext context, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
    var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
    // First, Creating User role as each role in User Manager  
    List<IdentityRole> roles = new List<IdentityRole>();
    roles.Add(new IdentityRole {Name = "Admin", NormalizedName = "ADMINISTRATOR"});
    roles.Add(new IdentityRole { Name = "Member", NormalizedName = "MEMBER" });
    roles.Add(new IdentityRole { Name = "Librarian", NormalizedName = "LIBRARIAN" });
    roles.Add(new IdentityRole { Name = "Borrower", NormalizedName = "BORROWER" });
    roles.Add(new IdentityRole { Name = "Reader", NormalizedName = "READER" });

   //Then, the machine added Default User as the Admin user role
    foreach (var role in roles)
    {
        var roleExit = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role.Name);
        if (!roleExit)
        {
            context.Roles.Add(role);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    //Next, I create an Admin Super User who will maintain the LMS website panel
    var userAdmin = new ApplicationUser()
    {
        UserName = "TrueMan",
        Email = "alpha@lms.com",
    };
    string userPWD = "Alpha@Mega";
    var chkUser = userManager.AddPasswordAsync(userAdmin, userPWD);
    if (chkUser.IsFaulted)
    {
        await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin", NormalizedName = "ADMINISTRATOR" });
    }
    userAdmin = await userManager.FindByNameAsync("TrueMan");
    await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(userAdmin, "Admin");
    //await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get you right but if you want to create user in admin role I'd do something like following.

```
private async Task CreateRoles(ApplicationDbContext context, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
    var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
    // First, Creating User role as each role in User Manager  
    List<IdentityRole> roles = new List<IdentityRole>();
    roles.Add(new IdentityRole {Name = "Admin", NormalizedName = "ADMINISTRATOR"});
    roles.Add(new IdentityRole { Name = "Member", NormalizedName = "MEMBER" });
    roles.Add(new IdentityRole { Name = "Librarian", NormalizedName = "LIBRARIAN" });
    roles.Add(new IdentityRole { Name = "Borrower", NormalizedName = "BORROWER" });
    roles.Add(new IdentityRole { Name = "Reader", NormalizedName = "READER" });

   //Then, the machine added Default User as the Admin user role
    foreach (var role in roles)
    {
        var roleExit = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role.Name);
        if (!roleExit)
        {
            context.Roles.Add(role);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    await CreateUser(context, userManager)
    }
}

private async Task CreateUser(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    var adminUser = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync("alpha@lms.com");
    if (adminUser != null)
    {
        if (!(await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(adminUser.Id, "Admin")))
            userManager.AddToRoleAsync(adminUser.UserName, "Admin");
    }
    else
    {
        var newAdmin = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            UserName = "TrueMan",
            Email = "alpha@lms.com",
        };
        await userManager.CreateAsync(newAdmin, "Alpha@Mega");
        await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(newAdmin.userName, "Admin");
    }
}
```

Could you please specify where exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

First please check if the [AspNetRoles] tables contains duplicates of admin and delete them. I think this line should be:

`var roleExit = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role.NormalizedName);`

and then:

```
string userPWD = "Alpha@1Mega";    
await userManager.CreateAsync(userAdmin, userPWD);
var user =  await userManager.FindByNameAsync("TrueMan");
if(!(await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Admin")))
    await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
```

Answer (score 0):

from the //Next, I create an Admin Super User who will maintain the LMS website panel, when I execute with command line: dnx web; I have the respond as "Access is denied". It seems that I cannot have missed some password validation.

Answer (score 0):

This code works when I create a new project, but I don't want to have userId with the long id var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync("7bd66984-a290-4442-a9f8-5659e01b0c06"); Therefore, I want my first Admin assigning to the the Admin Super User in order to change to assign another user roles.

```
private async Task CreateRoles(ApplicationDbContext context, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
    var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
    // First, Creating User role as each role in User Manager  
    List<IdentityRole> roles = new List<IdentityRole>();
    roles.Add(new IdentityRole {Name = "Admin", NormalizedName = "ADMINISTRATOR"});
    roles.Add(new IdentityRole { Name = "Member", NormalizedName = "MEMBER" });
    roles.Add(new IdentityRole { Name = "Librarian", NormalizedName = "LIBRARIAN" });
    roles.Add(new IdentityRole { Name = "Borrower", NormalizedName = "BORROWER" });
    roles.Add(new IdentityRole { Name = "Reader", NormalizedName = "READER" });

   //Then, the machine added Default User as the Admin user role
    foreach (var role in roles)
    {
        var roleExit = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role.Name);
        if (!roleExit)
        {
            context.Roles.Add(role);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
//    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync("7bd66984-a290-4442-a9f8-5659e01b0c06");
        //    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
}
```